# Infinispan RemoteCache in an Apache Spark task - RemoteCache not serializable

Tags: apache-spark, infinispan

I'm trying to stream events from a kafka topic and save them to Infinispan.

Infinispan is deployed as a standalone server - so not embedded.

Having submitted my Spark task, I add a message to the Kafka topic for the task to consume. As it tries to do that, there's an exception:

```
Error running job streaming job 1430222654000 ms.0 org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
...
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.RemoteCacheImpl
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.RemoteCacheImpl, value: org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.RemoteCacheImpl@43a5194d)
```

Any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above error can happen in Spark when you declare a reference to a field in the master driver (outside the task) and then reference it in the workers (inside the task). Since RemoteCacheImpl is not Serializable, it cannot be shipped over the network. 
Try to obtain the reference to RemoteCache inside the task itself instead of relying in the closure to do so.

Comment: I had the RemoteCache instance initialized on startup (which makes it reside in the master). Then I tried to reference the initialized cache in foreachRDD() which would require serialization. What I'm essentially doing is stream.map(parse).countByValue().foreachRDD { rdd => rdd.foreach(saveToInfinispan) }. I have to initialize the RemoteCache inside saveToInfinispan. Initializing it inside foreachRDD() is not enough. Am I wrong in thinking this is less than efficient? Is there a more reasonable way? In any case your answer is correct and thank you!

Comment: You might be interested on the Infinispan Spark connector, saving  a DStream to a remote cache is one of supported use cases  http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/08/infinispan-spark-connector-01-released.html